# body height and min-height on window browser extend

Tags: html, css

[image]

How can I get rid of the white part under the browser window?
I have:

html, body
  height:100%, 
  min-height: 100%

Comment: question seems bit unclear

Comment: Provide more details read this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You think it's the body but it could be something else, which means a picture isn't enough to deduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are different bugs your mind.

I've had same problem and fixed by an ugly bypass.

1'st i made a vertical frameset (100%,*)

2'nd i toke inner.window.height to 102%

I dont know why, but it looks like, that the problem cames from the bars above. So you it seems a failure that got from browser developers.